# HBase command for Viewing Snapshots

Tags: hbase

I have created a few snapshots of my hbase tables.
Is there a way to see all the snapshots created in HBASE?
Something like list snapshots?

Comment: will you create QA style questions for remaining hbase shell commands?

Comment: added this to make it easier to find as opposed to going through the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things to be done here as the document says:

1) Turn on the snapshot support just set the " hbase.snapshot.enabled" to true

```
<property>
<name>hbase.snapshot.enabled</name>
<value>true</value>
```

2)Take the snapshot

```
$ ./bin/hbase shell
hbase> snapshot 'myTable', 'myTableSnapshot-122112'
```

3) List all the snapshots taken:

```
$ ./bin/hbase shell
hbase> list_snapshots
```

*There are other functionalities too just check out this : http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/ops.snapshots.html

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation:
List all snapshots taken (by printing the names and relative information).

```
$ ./bin/hbase shell
hbase> list_snapshots
```